# keep website menu on screen when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, static

I am trying to make it so my drop down menu will stay on the top of the screen (so no matter how far you scroll down the site menu is always at the top) when scrolling down on my website. This is the css and menu I am using for my website. Can someone PLEASE help me I have tried for days to accomplish this with no success.

```
<style>
    #cssmenu ul,
    #cssmenu li,
    #cssmenu span,
    #cssmenu a {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu: after, #cssmenu ul: after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
    #cssmenu a {
        color: #FF0000;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        min-width: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li {
        float: left;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
        background: #000 url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000), color-stop(100%, #000));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        filter: progid: dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000', endColorstr='#000', GradientType=0);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000, inset 0 10px 10px #000;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000, inset 0 10px 10px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000, inset 0 10px 10px #000;
        filter: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active a: hover {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000), color-stop(100%, #000));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0%, #000 100%);
        filter: progid: dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000', endColorstr='#000', GradientType=0);
        filter: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li a {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
        background: #000 url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left top;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #000 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000), color-stop(50%, #000), color-stop(51%, #000), color-stop(100%, #000));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #000 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #000 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #000 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #000 100%);
        filter: progid: dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000', endColorstr='#000', GradientType=0);
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
        line-height: 34px;
        padding: 0 35px;
        filter: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li a: hover {
        background: #000 url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #525252 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000), color-stop(50%, #000), color-stop(51%, #000), color-stop(100%, #525252));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #525252 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #525252 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #525252 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 0%, #000 50%, #000 51%, #c 100%);
        filter: progid: dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000', endColorstr='#000', GradientType=0);
        filter: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li: first-child a {
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li: last-child a {
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub: hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 36px;
        left: -1px;
        min-width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        /* IE7 */
        *width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
        border-top: 0 none;
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
        display: block;
        line-height: 120%;
        padding: 9px 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='Stream Portal'><a href="./home.html" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href="./home.html" >TV</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./justintv.html" >Justin</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://lmtv.us/#" >LM</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mtv.com/ontv/" >MTV</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.spike.com/episodes" >Spike</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cartoon-world.tv/cartoon-list/" >Toon</a></li>
                <li><a href="./tubtub.html" >TubTub</a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href="shows" >Veetle</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href="./home.html" >Movies</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./moviesearchframe.html" >Movie Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://topdocumentaryfilms.com/" >Documentaries</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://freeonlinemoviestream.co/" >Movie Stream</a></li>
                <li><a href="./megashare.html" >MegaShare</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cartoon-world.tv/movie-list/" >Toon</a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href="http://watch32.com/new-movies.html" >Watch32</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example (only had to add a few lines of js): http://jsfiddle.net/wHF97/

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#cssmenu').stickUp();
    });
});
```

It uses a jQuery plugin called stickUp.  Their main page also has a working example: http://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/#

Note: I included the stickUp plugin using the "External Resources" in the left-pane of the jsfiddle.

Comment: This is exactly want I was looking for, Just one last problem, I dont know how to include the java script,were wouldIplace it?

Comment: Go to its GitHub page: https://github.com/LiranCohen/stickUp Click Download Zip on the right-hand side of the page.  In there you will find a README file, the License, and a full working example.  But in short you would include the js file like any other in your HEAD tag: <script src="js/stickUp.min.js"></script>. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well the Menu is working perfectly now as far sticking to the top when I scroll and the whole menu working, but now about half a page under the menu is not click-able. Any idea's? portalwolf.com if you need to visually see what i mean.

Comment: Hit F12 to bring up your browsers console.  Click on the "console" tab.  All your pages have many errors.  Many iframes cannot be loaded.  And I do not see any of the "stickUp" code when viewing source of header bar iframe, are you sure you refreshed production?

Comment: Sorry, I had to get the site back to the working one, I have made a test page to work this out with until I get it all correct.http://streamportal.comuv.com/StreamPortal/Test.html  I have also fixed all the iframe issues I believe. It still not letting me click on the top part of the pages though.

Comment: I'll look at it later this evening

Comment: I got it now :). I just had to change the heigt from 1000px to 25 px in the html for the actually menu in the html and now it works flawlessly. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 3):

`#cssmenu {position:fixed;top:0px}`

Comment: This works as far as keeping it on the top of the screen, but it only shows the mail section of my menu and even the mail section doesn't have all the sub categories.

Comment: You have not included any other markup content in your question so I went with what I had. Feel free to use this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/ZcHas/) to show me what problems you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Used the css position:fixed attribute:

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus.en.html

Answer (score 0):

jQuery scroll() event and $(window).scrollTop() returns the current position of the window scrolled.  If that value goes above the position of the item you want to 'follow' the scroll, use addClass to give that item:  position:fixed; top:0;  That way, when the user scrolls down past the position of the item, it will suddenly (and nicely) move with the window scroll.  You may have to recalc the left of the item. If the position of the window is above, removeClass the fixed position.